# Orange data mining boxplots

Tags: orange

I wanted to ask as to how I can reduce the number of decimal points - in quartiles, mean, median etc. In the boxplots.

Also how can I order various boxplots.. e.g. if I want to create boxplots for say very rich, rich, middle class, poor, very poor in this order.

Also by default boxplots are horizontal. How can I make them vertical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no option to reduce the number of decimal points.
2. You can visualize subgroups, but you can't order them manually. The default is by variance or alphabetically.
3. You can't make box plots vertical.